# How do I pass prop to style object in vue Js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use an object to control the style of certain parts of an app as I'm trying to avoid inline styling. What how do I use Colour from props in the styling object below please?

```js
 data: () => ({   
         props: ['header', 'questions', 'index', 'colour'],
         sectionScore: [],  
         styling: {
             borderLeft: '10px solid ${this.colour}'
         }         
     }),
```

I'm using the object in the main body with :style="styling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the `props` option should be declared as a property outside the data option, second, define the `styling` property as a computed one :

```
props: ['header', 'questions', 'index', 'colour'],
data: () => ({   
         
         sectionScore: [],  
              
     }),

computed:{
   styling(){
     return {
             borderLeft: `10px solid ${this.colour}`
         }
  } 
}
```